# Formatação de data no Java e Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, servlet

Bom dia pessoal!
Estou tentando retornar uma data formatada, está no banco como data, mas para retorno poderia ser um string msm.
Alguns amigos indicaram dois modos, criando um método novo para formatação ou usando o LocalDate do java 1.8.

O problema é que, como sou iniciante e acabo perdido em algumas coisas, não sei como fazer pra retornar o getFormatado... vou por o código que acho que explicará melhor... estou tendo retorno com o Hibernate....

```
package model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.ForeignKey;




@Entity
@Table(name ="fornecedor")
public class Fornecedor extends Pessoa{


@Column
private Integer codigo;
@Column
private String pessoaContato;
@Column
private String cnpj;
@Column
private Date inicioAtividades;

// ********* Omiti os Get and Setters desnecessários pra pergunta :)    

public Date getInicioAtividades() {
    return inicioAtividades;
}
public void setInicioAtividades(Date inicioAtividades) {
    this.inicioAtividades = inicioAtividades;
}


// ********** Pediram pra eu acrescentar este método aqui, abaixo

public String getInicioFormatado() throws ParseException { 
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String data = sdf.format(inicioAtividades);
    return data;
}
```

O problema é, como faço pra chamar esse kra, já que no hibernate está assim:

```
public List<Fornecedor> listarFornecedores() {
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<Fornecedor> listaFornecedores = new ArrayList<Fornecedor>();
    query = session.createQuery("FROM Fornecedor");
    listaFornecedores = query.list();
    session.close();
    return listaFornecedores;
```

Será que alguém pode me dar essa luz aí?
Obrigado pessoal!!!

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias formas de você fazer o mapeamento, qual delas você irá usar depende da versão da JPA/ORM.

A partir da versão 5.0 o Hibernate passou a suportar a API de Date and Time do java 8. Basta você adicionar a dependência `hibernate-java8` ao seu projeto:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

A partir da versão 5.2 a dependência acima foi adicionada ao `core` do Hibernate e não é mais necessária. Em ambos os casos sua classe ficaria assim:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="fornecedor")
public class Fornecedor extends Pessoa{


    @Column
    private Integer codigo;
    @Column
    private String pessoaContato;
    @Column
    private String cnpj;
    @Column
    private LocalDate inicioAtividades;

    //...
    //Seus getters and setters normais, sem nenhuma conversão adicional
}
```

Caso você utilize uma versão anterior a 5.0 mas essa versão suporte JPA 2.1, você pode usar um `AttributeConverter<X, Y>`:

Nesse caso, você deveria implementar a seguinte classe:

```
public class LocalDateConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate localDate) {
        return Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date date) {
        return date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    }
}
```

E alterar sua classe fornecedor para:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="fornecedor")
public class Fornecedor extends Pessoa{


    @Column
    private Integer codigo;
    @Column
    private String pessoaContato;
    @Column
    private String cnpj;
    @Column
    @Convert(converter=LocalDateConverter.class)
    private LocalDate inicioAtividades;

    //...
    //Seus getters and setters normais, sem nenhuma conversão adicional
}
```

E por último, você poderia fazer as conversões nos seus getters and setters:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="fornecedor")
public class Fornecedor extends Pessoa{


    @Column
    private Integer codigo;
    @Column
    private String pessoaContato;
    @Column
    private String cnpj;
    @Transient
    private LocalDate inicioAtividades;

    public void setInicioAtividades(Date date) {
        inicioAtividades = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
    }

    @Column
    public Date getInicioAtividades() {
         Date.from(inicioAtividades.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
    }

    //...
    //Seus outros getters and setters 
}
```

Para você adicionar um método que formate LocalDate, basta fazer isso:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="fornecedor")
public class Fornecedor extends Pessoa{

 //Seus outros campos e métodos

    private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

    public String getInicioAtividadesFormatado() {
         return inicioAtividades.format(DATE_FORMAT);
    }
}
```

Edit:

Para você chamar o `getInicioAtividadesFormatado()` basta fazer isso:

```
classX.listarFornecedores().forEach(f -> {
    String inicioAtividades = f.getInicioAtividadesFormatado();
    //Faça o que quiser aqui
});
```

Ou se você quiser buscar do banco de dados apenas o `inicioAtividades`, você pode fazer assim:

```
public List<LocalDate> listarInicioAtividades() {
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    List<LocalDate> listaInicioAtividades = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
    query = session.createQuery("SELECT F.inicioAtividades FROM Fornecedor F");
    listaInicioAtividades = query.list();
    session.close();
    return listaInicioAtividades;
```

}

E para exibir a lista formatada:

```
final DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
listarInicioAtividades().forEach(i -> {
    string dataFormatada = i.format(format);
    //Faça o que quiser aqui
});
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, amigo, foi bem completa... mas ainda não consegui entender, é como faço para obter o retorno do getInicioAtividadesFormatado, já que não tem nenhuma anotação do hibernate e ele também não está no banco... eu uso o hibernate 5 :)

Comment: Editei a resposta para mostrar como obter o retorno.

Comment: Amigo, Obrigado. Vou tentar aqui e depois do horário do almoço dou uma resposta. 
Abraço!

Comment: Desculpe a demora pra responder. O que ainda não consegui entender, é como vou fazer na hora em que roda o select no hibernate e é criada a lista, em que momento eu chamo o getInicioAtividadesFormatado e faço a conversão, para ele entrar na lista no lugar do InicioAtividades.

Comment: @sounobre Para que você quer que ele entre no luga de `inicioAtividades`? Eu não consigo imaginar um cenário onde isso seria necessário. Você poderia dar o exemplo de uma situação onde você acha que isso deva ser feito?

Answer (score 0):

Notei que você não usou a anotação temporal disponibilizada na biblioteca Persistence 2.1 ou posterior que já vem junto com o NetBeans (me desculpe na confusão de termos, se for o caso), em caso de estares a usar o Eclipse acho que deverás baixas a biblioteca.

Nessa biblioteca temos 3 anotações diferentes:

1. **TemporalType.DATE**: Este grava somente a parte da data, no formato YYYY-MM-dd
2. **TemporalType.Time**: Este grava somente a hora.
3. **TemporalType.TimeStamp**: E este grava a data e a hora, não me lembro do formato porque raramente uso.

**Exemplo**:

```
@javax.persistence.Entity
@Table(name = "fornecedor")
public class Fornecedor extends Pessoa {

private Integer codigo;

private String pessoaContato;

private String cnpj;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dataInicioAtividades;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date horaInicioAtividades;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date dataFimAtividades;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date horafimAtividades;

//Getters and Setters
}
```

Para que gravar a data num dos formatos acima basta adicionar a anotação **@Temporal(parametro)**, e escolher o formato. Vais substituir no lugar de "parametro pelo tipo desejado".

E na recuperação da data ela já vai estar no formato pré-seleccionado, inclusive ele será gravado nesse formato.

**Ps**: Não é necessário adicionar as **anotações @Column** em todos os atributos, esta anotação é geralmente usada quando o nome do atributo é diferente do nome da coluna...